# Skip all rows if one row id is present in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have three tables with this relation:

```
T1.journo = T2.journo
T2.recid = T3.spid

        T1
ticketno  journo
   1        A1
   2        A2

    T2
journo recid
  A1    1
  A1    2
  A1    3
  A2    4
  A2    5
  A2    6


 T3
spid
 2
```

I want only those entries of T1 where T2.recid is not present in T3.spid.

Below query will just omit the 2nd row of T2. But I want all the rows of T2 with journo=A1 omitted because one of the recid of A1 is present in T3.

```
 select T1.* from T1 join T2 on T1.journo = T2.journo
 where T2.recid not in (select spid from T3)
```

Desired Output:

```
ticketno journo
   2       A2
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

To me, this sounds like `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2 join
                       t3
                       on t2.recid = t3.spid
                  where t2.journo = t1.journo
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use not in with a sub query.

```
declare @t1 table (ticketno int identity(1,1), journo varchar(2))

declare @t2 table (journo varchar(2), recid int identity(1,1))

declare @t3 table (spid int)

insert into @t1
values
('A1'),
('A2')

insert into @t2
values
('A1'),
('A1'),
('A1'),
('A2'),
('A2'),
('A2')

insert into @t3
values
(2)


select T1.* , T2.*
from @t1 T1 
inner join @t2 T2 on T1.journo = T2.journo
where T2.journo not in (select t22.journo from @t2 t22 where t22.recid in (select * from @t3))
```

Or, not exists correlated

```
where not exists(select t22.journo from  @t2 t22 where t22.recid in (select * from @t3) and t22.journo = T2.journo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Join T2 on T3 with left a left join. group on the t1 variables then do a having check of COUNT(t3.spid) = 0.
Any nulls shouldn't be counted and so zero on the count is what your looking for.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM @t1 t1
JOIN @t2 t2 ON t2.journo = t1.journo
LEFT JOIN @t3 t3 ON t3.spid = t2.recid
GROUP BY t1.ticketno, t1.journo
HAVING COUNT(t3.spid) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL, the ugly but necessary part of our lives:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT a1.journo
, SUM(spid_present) AS 'total_spids'
    FROM
        (SELECT T2.journo
        , T2.ticketno
        , CASE
            WHEN t3.spid IS NOT NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'spid_present'
        FROM T2
        LEFT JOIN T3
        ON T2.recid = T3.spid) a1
GROUP BY a1.journo) a2
    ON T1.journo = a2.journo
    AND a2.total_spids = 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using EXCEPT:

```
    create table t1 (ticketno int, journo char(2))
    insert into t1 values (1, 'A1'), (2, 'A2')

    create table t2 (journo char(2), recid int)
    insert into t2 values ('A1', 1), ('A1', 2), ('A1', 3), ('A2', 4), ('A2', 5), ('A2', 6)

    create table t3 ([SPID] int)
    insert into t3 values (2)

    select t1.* from t1 
    except 
    select t1.*  
    from t1 
    inner join t2 on t2.journo = t1.journo 
    inner join t3 on t2.recid = t3.[SPID]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SQL query.

```
select T.* from T1 , T2 a where T1.journo = a.journo and a.recid not exists (select 1 from T3, T2 where T2.recid= T3.spid and T2.recid =a.reci);
```

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, simple join

```
select t1.* from #t1 t1
join #t2 t2
on t1.journo <> t2.journo
join #t3 t3
on t2.recid = t3.spid
```

Comment: t2 will now join on t1 where journo doesn't match t2 journo, so you'll end up with results which have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: let me know what you got..?

Comment: Your trying to join on journo. So if you tell T1 & T2 to join on journo's that don't match. So if T1 is "A1" and T2 is "A1" it won't match... not if T2 is "A2" it will now correctly join T1 "A1" with T2 "A2" because they don't match.

Comment: No. `t1.journo <> t2.journo` is true. when t1.'A2' and t2 'A1'. Then, t1 is returns `A2` row... My query never returns t2.A2. Due to, `t2.recid = t3.spid`.... would you try my query...?